# Using Jquery val() on a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Among other things I am trying to alert the selected value in the 'Amount' drop down box which is a list of numbers from 1 to 10. The list is generated and then inserted in to a div.

```
// generate the amount dropdown list
var dropdown = "<select name=\"amount\">";
for(var i=1; i <= MAX_PRINT; i++) {
    dropdown = dropdown + "<option>" + i + "</option>"
}
dropdown = dropdown + "</select>";

jQuery("#" + divId).html("<div>Amount: " + dropdown + "</div></div>");


var amount = 1;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    amount = jQuery("#amount").val();
    alert(amount);
});
```

My question is: Why does it produce 'undefined' when I alert the amount? I am expecting it to return the selected number

Comment: It alerts `undefined` because an element with ID `amount` does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you give your select an id—right now it just has a name.  As a result, your `jQuery('#amount')` selector is not returning anything, which is why the alert is showing 
`undefined`.

```
var dropdown = "<select id='amount' name='amount'>";
```

Comment: The `value` attribute is not needed though.

Comment: @Felix - with no value .val() will by default return the text of the selected option?

Comment: @AdamRackis value attribute not needed it's working fine without this also here http://jsfiddle.net/wdtkf/

Comment: Yes, that's actually just how the DOM interface works (i.e. it's not a jQuery feature).

Comment: Just a reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-value-OPTION

Answer (score 3):

you are using  `amount = jQuery("#amount").val();` for that you have to give your dropdown an id

```
var dropdown = "<select name=\"amount\" id=\"amount\">";
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wdtkf/)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2-3 Approach to get a selected value from `<select>`

- use [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)
- use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- use [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

Comment: Nothing! but above are just made for this kind of purpose. `.val` is parent at all :)

Answer (score 0):

The `id` is missing on your dropdown.

```
// Generate the amount dropdown list
var dropdown = "<select id="amount" name=\"amount\">";
for(var i=1; i <= MAX_PRINT; i++) {
    dropdown = dropdown + "<option>" + i + "</option>"
}
dropdown = dropdown + "</select>";

jQuery("#" + divId).html("<div>Amount: " + dropdown + "</div>/div>");

var amount = 1;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    amount = jQuery("#amount").val();
    alert(amount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if this works for you:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var amount = jQuery("select[name='amount']").val();
    alert(amount);
});
```